# How to ignore all possible cases for a dynamic word in a java string with help of java regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a sample query as:

```
create table Temp as select col1,col2 from mydb;
create table Filter as select col1 from Temp;
```

In the above String `Temp` and `Filter` both can be in any case.

i.e either upper,lower,camel or in toggle case.

How to ignore all possible combinations like camel-case,toggle-case for temporary table and replace it inside  the string.

Below is the below code that I tried:
Here query parameter  contains the above two strings and are separated by ";".
Key contains Temp/Filter.

```
public String replaceQuery(String query,String key){
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  String regx = "[a-zA-Z0-9]";
  Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regx);
  String[] ss = query.split(";");
  for(String str : ss){
    Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(str);
    while(mat.find()){
    }
 }
}
```

But I am not able to proceed further how I can remove all cases for the word Temp/Filter and replace it inside the String.
Can any one help me in this regard?

Comment: Shouldn't String's `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` do the trick for comparison?

Comment: No. toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() make it something as temp /TEMP.But how about the Temp / tEmP.

Comment: `"tEmP".toLowerCase().equals("TEMP".toLowerCase())` will return `true`

Comment: But user can type Temp/temp/TEMP/tEmp...any combinations.So how I can ignore all possible cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pattern `CASE_INSENSTIVE` flag as part of your Pattern.

Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("TEMP"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Here is an example for the query:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp AS SELECT col1,col2 from mydb;
```

where the word `Temp` will be replaced by `MyTempTable`

Notice how the `key` is set to `TEMP` but it will not matter

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE Temp AS SELECT col1,col2 from mydb;";
    String key = "TEMP";
    String newKey = "MyTempTable";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(key), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(query);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, newKey);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    String newQuery = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(newQuery);
}
```

And the output:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTempTable AS SELECT col1,col2 from mydb;
```

Comment: I am using a loop to process both the query. i.e create table Temp as select col1,col2 from mydb;
create table Filter as select col1 from Temp; But only the first query is getting replaced,not the second one.How I can process both the query